# Proving/Disproving Injectivity?

Tags: math

I'm in a Discrete Structures class (Computer Science Professor is teaching) and I recently got this problem on a quiz. I was under the assumption that this function was not injective, as there are x values between -1 and 0 that map to the same Y value. What am I doing wrong here?

Problem statement (verbatim):

```
Prove that: F(x) = y = X^2 + x for x in R ,and x > -1; and y in R
Injective

Let x1=-4/5 and x2=-1/5
(-4/5)2+(-4/5)=(-1/5)2+(-1/5)
-4/25= -4/25
```

Therefore, this function is not injective. It is not injective because two points on the function have equivalent outputs.

My professor responded with:

When using direct proof, do not use a particular case.  Direct proof is for all x or all y.
You are confused about injection.  If two distinct x arrive top the same y, then yes, it's not injective.  This function is injective. -10

Comment: You have provided two distinct inputs x1, x2 > -1 such that F(x1) = F(x2). Therefore F is not injective, and you have prooved it. I suspect there is some miscommunication here as it's clear the professor expects the function he gave to be injective.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm going to go to his office hours and ask him why he said that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be asked on [math.se].

Comment: Good work, OP, however, the question is off topic here; in the future try math.stackexchange.com for stuff like that.